# Two if clauses in one sentence?

Tags: clauses

I am curious about whether sentences whose structure resembling that of those following sentences are still considered fine and commonly used.

> 1 . *If you are planning to avoid rainy days would you be on a trip, then check the weather forecast.*
>   2 . *Even If he intended to run in the corridor should he be not caught, he still deserves punishment.*
>   3 . *If you'd been with me had all the others been against me, then I must have been happy.*

Do those *would, should, had* make sense to you? Do they seem like conditionals?

Lastly, as I just made up all these sentences they may have some errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one conditional.

> Should you ever be on a trip to a foreign land, if you want to stay dry there, you would do well to learn their expression for "chance of rain".

But your examples are ungrammatical in their placement of the conditional clauses and in their tenses. Some of your so-called *irrealis* forms can be expressed without the modal using simple present or simple past tense.

In #2, "He still deserves punishment" is clear and grammatical, but the conditional statements "Even if ... should he be not caught" must be reworded to make sense.

Even if he should not be caught, if he ran in the corridor, he still deserves punishment.

Even if he was not caught in the act, he still deserves punishment, if he ran in the corridor.

In #3, "must have been happy" is probably not what you want there. It could make sense if you had amnesia, say, and did not remember how you had felt.

If you had been with me, even if all the others had been|were against me, I would|should have been happy.

I would have been happy if you had been with me, even if all the others had been|were against me.

Answer (score -1):

I would not call your examples ungrammatical with regard to the placement of the conditional clauses; I can understand them as nested conditionals, even in the word sequence as you gave them, but the "should", "would","had" used in this way as conditionals, do sound stilted and quaint (and "would you be" in #1 seems to need to be replaced with ", should you be" or ",were you to be" or "if you were" or "while you are".) But as TRomano pointed out, these types of conditionals work better at the beginning of a sentence.  "Had I known it was going to rain, I would have brought my umbrella."  or a double conditional "Had I brought my umbrella, and had it not rained, I would have felt silly as well."

(Incidentally, each of your examples would have been more digestible with a comma before the second conditional phrase.)

Comment: Not my downvote. But "had all the others been against me" could be parenthetic only if it were introduced with an "even if" or an "although".  And in #2, the "even if" is attached to the wrong clause.

Answer (score -1):

An example of a sentence which contains two if-clauses came up on the Internet today:

'Justin Trudeau could be facing one the biggest government strikes in Canadian history if the country’s largest federal employee union votes for work stoppages this month if the Prime Minister doesn't work to meet their proposed wage increases.'

SOURCE: The Daily Digest

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/440825)

Comment: It's such an involved sentence perhaps the source involves irony.